# Chloropleth of chicago has a strange tilt to it that I cannot fix

Tags: python, geospatial, geojson, altair, graphing

I am trying to make a chlorpleth of environmental inspections in every chicago ward. I am mapping [this dataset of environmental inspections in chicago found on the city of chicago data porta](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Environment-Sustainable-Development/CDPH-Environmental-Inspections/i9rk-duva)l to [this geojson file of different wards also from city of chicago data](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-Wards-2015-2023-/sp34-6z76?fbclid=IwAR3jXC7Sr9JLdRlWUVDhWVUb1NZTPokT88BCxM7OsHGcBSIInsMYoHcoJQ4). If you do not want to download the files, there is a screenshot of the geomoetry of the geodataframe.

I will attach how I merged them, and the end result, for as much transparency as I can

```
inspections_df = pd.read_csv('CDPH_Environmental_Inspections.csv')
geometry = [Point(lon, lat) for lon, lat in zip(inspections_df['LONGITUDE'], inspections_df['LATITUDE'])]
inspections_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(inspections_df, geometry=geometry, crs=wards_gpd.crs)
joined_data = gpd.sjoin(wards_gpd, inspections_gdf, how='inner', op='contains').set_crs(epsg=4326)
ward_inspection_counts = joined_data.groupby('ward')['LOCATION'].count().reset_index().rename(columns = {'LOCATION':'Inspections'})
wards_connector = wards_gpd[["geometry","ward"]]
inspections_connected = pd.merge(wards_connector, ward_inspection_counts, how='outer', on='ward')
choropleth_map_Inspections = alt.Chart(inspections_connected).mark_geoshape(stroke='white',
    strokeWidth=0.6).encode(
    color=alt.Color('Inspections:Q', scale=alt.Scale(zero = False, scheme='inferno')),
    tooltip=['ward','Inspections']
).properties(
    width=600,
    height=400,
    title='Inspections in every Chicago Ward'
)

choropleth_map_Inspections
```

[Final Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlTK0.png)

If anybody knows, why does this graph have a weird tilt? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: What kind of projection is being used to convert lat/lon coordinates to x/y?  Every projection introduces some amount of distortion since the Earth isn't flat.

Comment: Default projection is `equalEarth`, see also https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/marks/geoshape.html#cartesian-coordinates